# Blender mesh-cleanup reduces number of vertices but in Three.js it doesn't

Tags: three.js, blender

I have a big problem. In Blender I reduce the number of vertices of models by going to edit mode, then mesh, then cleanup and the various options. Let's say the initial vertices count was 10000, after the cleanups it goes to 2000. When I export the model to glb and import it in Three.js the vertices count goes back to 10000. Do I have to select something in Blender when exporting to avoid this problem?

If anybody knows a solution, well thanks.